# How to check model instance variables are being assigned in RSpec Controller specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2

I'm new to RSpec, but I'm attempting to create RSpec2 controller specs for some new functionality in a Rails 3 app. I have a model that belongs_to :user and I want to ensure that the user is getting set by my controller when I create a new instance of my model.

The currently logged on user should be the user that is assigned to the model in the create action.  I'm having trouble getting my specs to work.  Here's what I have

```
# this was generated by rspec-rails and sets up my mock model
def mock_plan_order(stubs={})
  (@mock_plan_order ||= mock_model(PlanOrder).as_null_object).tap do |plan_order|
    plan_order.stub(stubs) unless stubs.empty?
  end
end

# here's the actual test that's not working
context "user logged in" do
    before(:each) do
      login_user # this logs in and sets @current_user - this is working
    end

    describe "POST create" do
        # the spec that is not working
        it "sets the user id to the logged on user" do
          PlanOrder.stub(:new).with({"days_per_week" => 3, "description"=>"Test", "purpose_id"=>1 }) { mock_plan_order(:save => true) }
          post :create, :plan_order =>{"days_per_week" => 3, "description"=>"Test", "purpose_id"=>1 }
          assigns(:plan_order).user.should equal(@current_user)
        end
   end
end
```

Here's the spec output

```
1) PlanOrdersController user logged in POST create with valid params sets the user id to the logged on user
 Failure/Error: assigns(:plan_order).user.should equal(@current_user)

 expected #<User:58754688> => #<User:0x3808680 @name="User_1">
      got #<PlanOrder:58689360> => #<PlanOrder:0x37f8750 @name="PlanOrder_1010">
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stubbed the creation of the plan_order object, so no user will be set. Either don't mock/stub, add a mock to ensure that the user is being set.